# runtime generated DataProvider for testNG

Tags: java, testing, testng

i want to create an extension for testNG. i want to add a possibility to provide parameters as strings, parse those strings and convert to complex types. such implicit data provider with less boilerplate. something like [zohhak](http://zohhak.googlecode.com) for junit.

```java
@Test
@MyParameters({"1, 2014-02-12",
               "3, null",
               "7, 2012-08-23"})
public void testMethod(int number, Date date) {
  ...
}
```

but i have completely no idea how to do it simply. i know there are listeners but it doesn't look like they can execute same method many times or provide parameters. The only way i can think of is to on-the-fly generate a class with a data provider and assign that data provider. is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Uhm, a `@DataProvider` isn't that much boilerplate code, is it? And it Just Works(tm), so why not use it?

Comment: because 1) it splits test method from the parameters 2) uses string to match them 3) creating complex/user types is still a boilerplate 4) to learn

Comment: I don't see the problem with 1. Especially since it means you can use a data provider with _several tests_. As to 2, I don't see the problem either -- your method also uses strings and it is even worse since you need to parse them into usable types... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I did something similar. Will try to explain what I did:

Env: TestNg + Spring + XMLBeans

There was only one DataProvider (org.testng.annotations.DataProvider) for all tests. 
It received an xml document which had parameters definitions e.g.

```
<test name="test1">
    <case>
        <parameter type=”bla.bla.bla.MyBean”>bean_id</parameter>
        <parameter type="int">1</parameter>
        <parameter type=”boolean”>true</parameter>
    </case>
</test>
```

The test method looks like this

```
@Test(dataProvider = "MyProvider")
public void test1(MyBean beanObj, int intParam, Boolean boolParam)
{
    …
}
```

So, the only thing I had is to implement a “convert” method. The method which creates Object[][] based on input xml.

The “bad” thing is that “convert” method should be aware of all types you need. So, I my case it was rather big.

The “good” thing is that there is only one data provider and you don’t need to cast objects in your tests.